# Why I am getting class not found exception for Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am developing an web app Using : eclipse IDE(Marse), Java 8, Apache tomcat 8, MySQL.
My code for user registration is as follows:

```
System.out.println("Connecting....");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Class found....");
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db";
            String user="root";
            String password="root";
            System.out.println("success");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            String query = "insert into login (username,password,emailid,country,city) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1,b.getUsername());
            ps.setString(2,b.getPassword());
            ps.setString(3,b.getEmailid());
            ps.setString(4,b.getCountry());
            ps.setString(5,b.getCity());
            int count=ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
```

My code is also correct and also I **added mysql-connector-java-5.1.36** by using *Build path>add_external_jar* option in eclipse. But still why it gives me such a exception ?

> Connecting....
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at model.InfoModel.SaveInfo(InfoModel.java:14)
>       at controller.Register_user.doGet(Register_user.java:35)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: check whether in `Order and Export` tab your .jar is ticked or not?

Comment: Try to  `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;` in the same class. If it works then your classForName should work.

Comment: Where did I search for Order and Export tab

Comment: @FranMontero I imported that now but it shows Yellow underline below import statement (unused import statement)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right click on the Project, go to `Properties`. Choose `Deployment Assembly` (if not found, read the update part) from the left pane. Check if `Java Build Path Entries` are provided. If not, click on `Add` and include it. If it is already present, click `Add` to include your connector jar as `Archive`. Do a `Project`>`Clean`, restart your Server.

### Update

If the Project is not being Faceted, you will not find this option. You can click on `Project Facets`, convert to faceted structure and add `Dynamic Web Module` and related dependencies.

### Update

Web Deployment Assembly Problem.
This answer is helpful in most cases.

Comment: Oh !!! Great... This resolves my problem :)

Comment: only `Project->Clean` worked for me